# How to replace drupal-render-placeholder manually?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I've got the element with following plain string (result of some kind of [side effect](https://www.drupal.org/node/2899439)):

> `<drupal-render-placeholder callback="Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::lazyBuilder" arguments="0=myform&amp;1=full&amp;2" token="p8BOEzhVedaNVMwuFKbSbXYvHJtJev-99V8a_12Hv4A"></drupal-render-placeholder>`

Which method/function can I call to manually replace this render placeholder with relevant content?

My idea as a workaround is to do this:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_form_element
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_form_element(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#title'] == 'Specific Title') {
    $variables['element']['#value'] = REPLACE_PLACEHOLDER($variables['element']['#value']);
  }
}
```

Note that in `$variables['children']`, the placeholder looks in different format for some reason:

> `<input data-drupal-selector="edit-taps" type="hidden" name="myform" value="1:&lt;drupal-render-placeholder callback=&quot;Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::lazyBuilder&quot; arguments=&quot;0=myform&amp;amp;1=full&amp;amp;2&quot; token=&quot;p8BOEzhVedaNVMwuFKbSbXYvHJtJev-99V8a_12Hv4A&quot;&gt;&lt;/drupal-render-placeholder&gt;:2" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the workaround which worked for me:

```
use Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_form_element
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_form_element(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#type'] == 'webform_computed_token') {
    $block = BlockViewBuilder::lazyBuilder('myform', 'full', 2);
    $block_content = render($block);
    $variables['children'] = Markup::create($block_content);
  }
}
```

I've used `$variables['children']`, since the final rendered content was in  there (not in `$variables['element']`). Above code has hardcoded `lazyBuilder` method with the arguments based on the data which are included in `<drupal-render-placeholder>`, since reading plain text and parsing the attribute values only to read which callback to call with which arguments would be too complex (as I didn't find any straight functions to read these placeholder tags, however I've posted complete solution below).

The above solution is basically the dirty workaround for the mentioned side effect (currently [unknown bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2899439)) as normally render placeholders should be part of the `#attached` element (see [`createPlaceholder()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21PlaceholderGenerator.php/function/PlaceholderGenerator%3A%3AcreatePlaceholder/8.4.x) in [`PlaceholderGenerator.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21PlaceholderGenerator.php/8.4.x)).

---

Here is the complete workaround which it did work for me (placed in: `mytheme.theme`):

```
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;
use Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder;

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_form_element
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_form_element(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#type'] == 'webform_computed_token') {
    // Dirty workaround for this bug: https://www.drupal.org/node/2899439;
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // Surpress the warnings for HTML load.
    $dom->loadHTML($variables['element']['#value'] ?: (string) $variables['children']);
    $placeholder = $dom->getElementsByTagName('drupal-render-placeholder');
    if (!empty($placeholder[0])) {
      $callback = $placeholder[0]->getAttribute('callback');
      $args = parse_str(Html::decodeEntities($placeholder[0]->getAttribute('arguments')), $args_arr);
      $element = call_user_func_array($callback, $args_arr);
      $content = render($element);
      $variables['children'] = Markup::create($content); // Replace the old markup.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, at least not with the data you've shown in the question.

You need the placeholder attached to `#attached` to execute the replacement. When rendering normally this bubbles up to the page level. But this looks like early rendering in such a way that the metadata is lost, otherwise you wouldn't report the issue.

For a workaround, why you don't replace the value with the render element of the webform you intend to place here:

```
$variables['element']['#value'] = [
  '#type' => 'webform',
  '#webform' => 'myform',
  '#default_data' => [],
];
```

This could be the final solution, if you use a custom token pattern for replacement.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `drupal-render-placeholder` tag inside final output isn't expected and this usually indicates the problem how the content is rendered.

So instead of replacing placeholder manually as in the [other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/243111/1908), rendering method should be fixed by using `renderer` service.

The common mistake is to use <del>`drupal_render($content)`</del> instead of `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($block_content)`.

My issue was related to [Block Token bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2899439) and example fix can be seen in this [patch file](https://www.drupal.org/node/2899439#comment-12202456).

Comment: Don't replace render() with renderRoot(), like you did in a lot of edits in other posts, because render() is used in most cases within a render context and you need render() to bubble up metadata. You only get trouble when you render too early without a render context. This produces not only orphaned placeholder tags like in your case, a lot of more bad things can happen.